# VBA Arrays looping to add new values object required error

Tags: arrays, vba, object

I am looping on 2 arrays and am getting an "object required error" have tried a few things but nothing seems to fix it, the arrays seem defined correctly - the one causing the issue ArrPnLDataD1:

'PnL Data D1 array

```
Dim RngPnLDataD1 As Range
Dim ArrPnLDataD1 As Variant

NbRowsPnLDataD1 = PnLD1WS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set RngPnLDataD1 = PnLD1WS.Range(PnLD1WS.Cells(1, 1), PnLD1WS.Cells(NbRowsPnLDataD1, 158))


ArrPnLDataD1 = RangeToArray2D(RngPnLDataD1)

For k = LBound(ArrPnLDataD1, 1) To UBound(ArrPnLDataD1, 1)

    For j = LBound(PricingDatesArr, 1) To UBound(PricingDatesArr, 1)

    If ArrPnLDataD1(k, 1) = PricingDatesArr(j, 1) Then 'THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ISSUE

    PricingDatesArr(k, 3) = ArrPnLDataD1(j, 77)

    End If

    Next j

Next k
```

The function below is used to get the array from a range

```
Public Function RangeToArray2D(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
Dim size As Integer
Dim inputValue As Variant, outputArray() As Variant

    inputValue = inputRange

    On Error Resume Next
    size = UBound(inputValue)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        RangeToArray2D = inputValue
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim outputArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        outputArray(1, 1) = inputValue
        RangeToArray2D = outputArray
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Where did you populate `PricingDatesArr`?

Comment: Same as ArrPnLDataD1 using the function, ArrPnLDataD1(k, 1) is getting the error "object required"

Comment: No, ArrPnLDataD1 is (1 to 14775, 1 to 158) PricingDatesArr (1 to 15069, 1 to 17)

Comment: The line below the supposed error line has the variables switched.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Error was due to mix up between k and j, thanks for spotting that. solved